# C++ Template: return larger value of two different types and preserve original type

Tags: c++, templates

I'm confused about this template example on: https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/templates/
If I called function with the values `GetMin(1, 0.1);`I get a result of 0. Assuming it's incorrect, how would you do it correctly while still returning the result as its original type (Meaning you can't set the return type of double and convert the result to a double).

```
template <class T, class U>
T GetMin (T a, U b) {
  return (a<b?a:b);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `std::common_type` ([docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type)) for getting common of 2 (or more) types (common type for T and U is the type that T and U can implicitly be converted to):

```
 template <class T, class U>
 typename common_type<T, U>::type GetMin (T a, U b) {
      return (a<b?a:b);
 }
```

Since C++14 the helper `common_type_t<T, U>` can also be used, to save some writing.

Comment: You should also compile with `-Wconversion -Werror`

Comment: How does this answer the question? OP wants to return *either* `T` or `U`, not the common type. This answer gives the impression that this is possible.

Comment: What OP is asking for is impossible.  GetMin(0.1, 1) and GetMin(1, 0.1) will return different answers because the output was arbitrarily chosen to be the type of the first and not the type of the second.  At best, you can get the compiler to warn you about it.

Comment: Would decltype(auto) return type work here?

Answer (score 1):

> how would you do it correctly while still returning the result as its original type

You can't do that, because the return value is decided at run-time, but the return type is decided at compile time. Assuming a common type that both of the arguments can be converted to is OK, here is one way implement that function:

```
template <typename T, typename Y>
auto GetMin(T const& a, Y const& b) {
  return (a < b ? a : b);
}
```

Result of the conditional operator is a common type that both operands can be converted to, so the return type is going to be `double` when you do `GetMin(1, 0.1);`. This is, most of the time, what you want anyway.

---

<sub>You could also do something like [this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/79v9Ys). But, why would you do that?</sub>